# Solve the following periodic problem Sturm-Liouville

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Solve the following periodic problem
$$u_{t}-u_{xx}=0, \quad -\pi<x<\pi,\quad t>0$$
$$u(-\pi,t)=u(\pi,t), \quad u_{x}(-\pi,t)=u_{x}(\pi,t), \quad t\geq 0  $$
$$u(x,0)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1 &    -\pi\leq  x\leq 0 \\
             \\0 &   \quad 0 \leq x\leq \pi \\
             \end{array}
   \right. $$
I'm trying to solve this Sturm-Liouville problem. But I haven't gotten a solution yet. How can I solve this problem? I need some help or a way to solve this problem. I would like to know a solution. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Separation of variables implies the spatial eigenfunctions are $X_{n}(x) = A_{n} \cos(\lambda_{n} x) + B_{n} \sin(\lambda_{n} x)$ with $\lambda_{n}$ to be determined from the boundary conditions. You can then solve the ODE in the temporal variable $T_{n}'(t) = - \lambda_{n} T_{n}$ and you get your solution as a superposition $$u = \sum_{n} X_{n} T_{n}$$ Finally, use the initial condition to determine the coefficients $A_{n}, B_{n}$ using the orthogonality relations.

Comment: @mattos can you translate your solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  u_t=X(x)T'(t)\\
  u_{xx}=X''(x)T(t)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

isolating X' with X and T' with T we get
$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}= -\lambda$

$X''(x)= -\lambda X(x)$
$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$

Since we know from the theory of ODEs that in this type of equation $X(x)=e^{rx}$, applying it on the equation we get

$r^2= -\lambda$
$r=\pm \sqrt{-\lambda}$
supposing $\lambda=n^2$
$r=\pm in$

$X(x)=b e^{inx} + c e^{-inx}$
$X(x)=b (cos(nx) +i sin(nx))+c(cos(-nx)+i sin(-nx))$
$X(x)=b (cos(nx) +i sin(nx))+c_2os(nx)-i sin(nx))$
$X(x)=(b +c)cos(nx) +i(b-c) sin(nx)$
$X(x)=B cos(nx) +C sin(nx)$

then we get $X_n(x)=B_ncos(nx) +C_n sin(nx)$

For $T$ we have

$\dfrac{d T(t)}{dt}= -n^2 T(t)$
$\dfrac{dT}{T}= -n^2 t$
$ln T(t) = -n^2 t + a$
$T(t)=e^{-n^2 t + a}$
$T(t)=Ae^{ -n^2 t}$

and $T_n(t)=A_ne^{ -n^2 t}$

Then

$u(x,t)= \sum_{n} X_n(x)T_n(t)$
$u(x,t)= \sum_{n} (B_ncos(nx) +C_n sin(nx))(A_ne^{ -n^2 t})$

We now have to apply the initial conditions to get $A_n$, $B_n$ and $C_n$

Comment: is the classical solution?

Comment: I don't know, this is the only method I know how to use. You could try using Laplace transforms to solve it, but I'm not experienced with it.